# Replacing a variable permanently in shell

Tags: command-line, text-processing, sed

I have file `<temp_test.sh>` in which I have defined a variable `Min_Inc=300000`.

I then want to get the user input to change the value of `Min_Inc`. I followed these steps.

1. Read the value using `echo $Min_Inc` and displayed it.
2. Sought User input for the new value and read it with `read New_Val`.
3. Tried replacing `Min_Inc=300000` with `Min_Inc=$New_Val` using `sed` as `sed 's/Min_Inc=300000/Min_Inc=$New_Val/'`

This gives an error message. Moreover, I want to make this change permanent which I can make by redirecting the output to another file.

Answer (score 1):

Variables aren't expanded inside single quotes. You either need to use double quotes:

```
sed -i "s/Min_Inc=300000/Min_Inc=$New_Val/" /path/file-name
```

Or break the quotes for the variable:

```
sed -i 's/Min_Inc=300000/Min_Inc='$New_Val'/' /path/file-name
```

The `-i` flag writes the value back to the file, you can even make a backup of the file that way by adding a string to the `-i` flag. For example `-i.bak` will create a backup file with the extension `.bak`.

Comment: Tried it with -i and it did not work but tried it without -i and it did.